# Unable to make a Async Post call to Here Maps positioning endpoint

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, here-maps-rest

When testing the call through Postman and a C# WebRequest it works, but I am unable to do the same using an HttpClient with a PostAsync or PostJsonAsync call.

Error: Unsupported Media Type, although application/json is required and applied.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                    .Accept
                    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://pos.api.here.com/positioning/v1/locate?app_id={id}&app_code={code}", content);
return response;
```

> StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent,
>   Headers:{ Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 13:38:37 GMT  Server: nginx-clojure 
>   Content-Type: application/json  Content-Length: 114}

WebRequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
    request.ContentType =  "application/json";
    request.Method =  "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(data);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
}

using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `WebRequest` code that worked? It may not be equivalent.

Comment: Shown, thanks @Gabr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences I see:

1. You are setting the `Accept` header in your `HttpClient` code, where you were not in your `WebRequest` code. This defines the type of data that *you* accept. If this API call does not return JSON, then it could be just saying "I have nothing to say to you then". You can try just deleting that whole line.
2. The `Content-Type` in your `HttpClient` code will be `application/json; charset=utf-8`, whereas you set it to just `application/json` in your `WebRequest` code. I don't see why the `charset` would make it choke, but if changing #1 doesn't work, you can try setting the `Content-Type` directly and see if it makes any difference:

```
var content = new StringContent("");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, that was it, changing my code as you suggested worked.